# How do I change the resolution on an Intel g31?

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, asus

why Ubuntu 11.10 don't support Intel g31? i can change resolution 1024x768. my display is unknown? I am new ubuntu user please help me, my motherboard is asus p5kpl-am.

Answer (score 1):

Well, try in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

should work, but I think the driver/kernel compilation is unstable. With me worked but sometimes it goes back to wrong resolution.
If it doesn't work at all, let's ask again.